# How to override mini-cart default template html file?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, requirejs-config.js

I have Magento 2.2.4 version, And I want to overwrite `Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html` file in my custom module. For this, I created `require-jsconfig.js` file at below path

> /app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html': 'Namespace_Module/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
  }
};
```

removed **"var"** folder from root and remove **`"pub/static/frontend"`** folder and run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But mini cart is showing blank. 
Can anyone help me to understand my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides requirejs-config.js files for overriding the `js` & `html` file to enhance the functionality of the existing `js` & `html`  files by simply manipulating them into your custom module.

To do that just follow the following guidelines.

- Create & register your custom module & create requirejs-config.js file at below location

> Magento_root/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

And below code in your requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html': 
              'Vendor_Module/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
  }
};
```

If you required to do very minor changes then instead of creating a module you can directly do that by simply overriding it with the help of your theme. For that just follow the below guidelines.

- Just copy the file from the below location

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

- Place it into your custom theme at the below location & make your changes there into that file

> Magento_root/app/design/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

So we can override any html file in this way.

> Note: After making the changes to deploy it properly please run the
>   below commands
>
> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento c:f
> ```

Comment: I tried to overwrite through requirejs-config.js not working

Comment: Did you checked that is it calling your page or the default old page there in your cart section? try to make different changes into both of them & see which change is coming there. try to deploy your static content & before that delete the generated folder & the var/cache folder contents.

Comment: After doing that I checked, it is calling the default file only. Not the updated one. But I can able to see my updated code under pub/static section. And I run below all command
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ ,
rm -rf var/,
rm -rf generated/,
php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento setup:di:compile,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy,
php bin/magento indexer:reindex,
php bin/magento cache:clean,
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Are you working on your local system or on the server? If you are working on the server then there is a possibility that some cache is set there try to remove that cache & also try with different browsers or browsers into incognito/safe mode because it can be possible that your browser cache is loading the old data!

Comment: I am working on a server and  open site in incognito/safe mode only

Comment: then it is the issue with the cache of the server check into the pub/static do it contains the other file also there?

Comment: other file mean ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90661/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-nilava-chakraborty).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check xml file here

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml
```

in line 27

```
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/item/default</item>
```

You have to create same file in your module
vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml
and add this content to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```